# Filter formula that excludes text found in a range from the filtered range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the FILTER function to remove undesirable items from a range in B3:B600.  The issue is that my current formula only excludes exact matches when using a list from a range as the criteria, or excludes partial matches when using a single cell.  I would like to simplify it and be able to remove both exact matches and partial matches from a list in a range.

Current formula:

```
=FILTER(B3:B600,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Q3:Q100,B3:B600)))*NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3:B600,R3:R100,0)))*(B3:B600<>""))
```

Since I sometimes need to use exact matches to exclude, I am using two ranges.  The first range is for excluding the partial matches, the second is for the exact matches. The reason is that some valid items might meet the partial criteria and be excluded if I were to use a one-size fits all filter.

Answer (score 2):

You may give a try to the following formula-

```
=FILTER(B3:B9,BYROW(B3:B9,LAMBDA(x,NOT(OR(COUNTIFS(x,"*"&D3:D5&"*"))))))
```

[image]